# moving only some part of files to another folder

Tags: python, directory, file-move

Hi everyone I´m trying now to move some files from one folder to another. The files that i have are

- results_1_1
- results_2_1
- results_3_1
- results_1_2
- results_2_2
- results_3_2

What i´d like  to get is to move files

- results_1_1
- results_2_1
- results_3_1 to one folder let´s call it A

other

- results_1_2
- results_2_2
- results_3_2 to another let´s call it B

I don´t want to do it manually because, in reality, I have much more files

I have created by python a new folder that I want to have

and so far about moving the files to another directory

```
import shutil
source_folder = r"C:/Users/...."
destination_folder= r"C:/Users/...."
files_to_move = ['results_1_3.dat']

for file in files_to_move:
    source = source_folder + file 
    destination = destination_folder + file 
    shutil.move(source,destination)
print("Moved!")
```

But with this program I can only move one file at a time I tried writing results_.+*3.dat', results**_3.dat' but I´m seeing an error all the time

Comment: I would use a for loop to place filenames into your `files_to_move` array, since it looks like the filenames increment by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.listdir` to find all the files in your directory.

This code finds all the files which names end with '1'.

```
import os
files_to_move = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.split('.')[0][-1] == '1']
```

You can also add an extension check if necessary:

```
files_to_move = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.split('.')[0][-1] == '1' and f.split('.')[1] == 'dat']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list all files in your directory using `os.listdir(source_folder)`

If you have mixed files in your directory, you can select your results files with something like this

```
files_to_move = [x for x in os.listdir(source_folder) if all(j in x for j in ['results', '.dat'])]
```

I would then create a dictionary containing the destination folders associated with the numbers in your results file.

```
destination_A = r'/path/to/destinationA'
destination_B = r'/path/to/destinationB'

moving_dict = {
    '1': destination_A,
    '2': destination_B
}
```

You can then move your files based on the filename

```
for file in files_to_move:
    destination_folder = moving_dict[file[:-4].split('_')[-1]]
    source = source_folder + file 
    destination = destination_folder + file 
    shutil.move(source,destination)
```